# PANIC: Missing emulator engine program for 'x86' CPU. ON UBUNTU

Tags: ubuntu, android-emulator, ubuntu-18.04

I cant start my emulators. I tried to start it from AVD manager but got this error.
[image]

Then I tried to launch it from Terminal but now I get this.
[image]

Answer (score 6):

Just had the same problem. It turns out that now the good path emulator is in `.../android_sdk/emulator`, not in `.../android_sdk/tools`. In your case you need to run it like:

```
cd ~/Android/Sdk/emulator
./emulator -avd <name of your avd>
```

Comment: Thanks I think it would work a year ago :D

Comment: This also worked for me on windows 10

Answer (score 0):

Simply follow the below steps specific to Fedora 34. 
Go to:
 `/home/{username}/Android/sdk/emulator`
`./emulator -list-avds`
`./emulator @avdName`